# how to make 1-index based array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, excel

it is a simple question - how to make an object array in VB.NET with indexes starting from 1?

I need such an object to write back a range to an Excel spreadsheet and it accepts only 1-based indexing.

When I read a range from Excel, it creates a 1-based object in VB.NET automatically, but when I am trying to create another object, it doesn't allow me to set lBound as 1.

Comment: Why not just populate a null value for the 0 based index?

Comment: Because xlObject.Range("myrange") = VBNETObj requires a 1-based object. Actually, I can copy an object that I previously read from Excel and it will be 1-based index, but cannot create a new one.

Comment: I see....I would write a custom class that inherits from System.Collections.CollectionBase. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xth2y6ft(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @J-MANMORGAN: please don't ever post a .NET 1.1 link unless the question is about .NET 1.1. All the links in that article are also .NET 1.1 links, so readers may get stuck in a maze of .NET 1.1 articles.

Comment: @JohnSaunders My mistake, I didnt see that.

Comment: All arrays in VB are zero based, but it does not mean you need to set/get the value at zero. Just start filling in at 1 and ignore zero.  Just avoid using `For Each`, use something like a `For i as interger = 1 to ?`

Comment: Excuse me @Steve "All arrays in VB are zero based" but for this question the array MUST BE one based. Excel throws an exception if you try to write a zero based array back to an Excel range.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array.CreateInstance` to achieve what you want.

```
    ' create an array of 10 items with lower bound index of 1
    Dim arrayStartingWith1 As Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Integer), New Integer(0) {10}, New Integer(0) {1})

    ' this is now incorrect
    ' arrayStartingWith1(0) = 1

    ' this is correct
    arrayStartingWith1(1) = 1
    arrayStartingWith1(10) = 1
```

Comment: The code has errors on the assignment statements when I copy and paste it.

Comment: s/b .SetValue and .GetValue

Comment: @dbasnett Which line?

Answer (score 0):

This is a two-dimensional array otherwise similar to Szymon's answer.

```
Public Shared Function GetBlankRangeArray(RowCount As Integer, ColumnCount As Integer) As Object(,)

    Dim arrayStartingWith1 As Array =
        Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Object),
                             New Integer(1) {RowCount, ColumnCount},
                             New Integer(1) {1, 1})

    Return arrayStartingWith1

End Function
```

[Array.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance)